# Typescript returns interface of type instead of type

Tags: javascript, typescript

So i have the following class:

```
export abstract class SuperIO {
    async http<T>(
        request: RequestInfo
    ): Promise<IHttpResponse<T>> {
        const response: IHttpResponse<T> = await fetch(
            request
        );
        try {
            response.parsedBody = await response.json();
        } catch (ex) {
        }

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response;
    }

    async get<T>(
        path: string,
        body: any,
        args: RequestInit = {method: "get", body: JSON.stringify(body)}
    ): Promise<IHttpResponse<T>> {
        return await this.http<T>(new Request(path, args));
    };
}
```

where `IHttpResponse` look like this:

```
interface IHttpResponse<T> extends Response{
    parsedBody?: T;
}
```

Now i wish to use this class so i have created the following:

```
import {SuperIO} from "../Framework/SuperIO";


export interface IContentData {
    id: number;
    url: string;
    htmlTag: string;
    importJSComponent: string;
    componentData: string
}

export class ContentIOService extends SuperIO {

    public async GetContent(url: string) {
        const response = await super.get<IContentData>(url, {});

        this.ProcessResponse(response);

    }

    private ProcessResponse(ContentData: IContentData) {

    }
}
```

However at the `this.ProcessResponse` i get the following error:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'IHttpResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContentData'.   Type 'IHttpResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'IContentData': id, htmlTag, importJSComponent, componentData

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Comment: I think your error above is cut off.  

TS2345: Argument of type 'IHttpResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContentData'.   Type 'IHttpResponse'...?

Comment: The full error reads:
TS2345: Argument of type 'IHttpResponse<IContentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContentData'.   Type 'IHttpResponse<IContentData>' is missing the following properties from type 'IContentData': id, htmlTag, importJSComponent, componentData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const response` is of the type `IHttpResponse<IContentData>`

You need to pass `response.parsedBody` to your method.

```
    public async GetContent(url: string) {
        const response = await super.get<IContentData>(url, {});

        response?.parsedBody && this.ProcessResponse(response.parsedBody);

    }

    private ProcessResponse(ContentData: IContentData) {

    }
```

Comment: IF i do that i get: TS2345: Argument of type 'IContentData | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IContentData'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IContentData'.

Comment: That's because parsedBody might be undefined (you have a ? after the parameter). You can check if it exists first. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Todd Skelton. is there any way i can improve and avoid the check?